# How do you load an accordion all closed, then open onclick?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to initially display this accordion with all panels closed at first (or onload) then open when a user clicks. Any ideas how to update this? Maybe I should add another function? Not 100% sure what to do here, help would be awesome.

Here's the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Head -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Which devices are compatible with ThePhotostick Omni? </h3>
  <div>
    <p>Almost all major Android, iPhone, and iPad devices!</p><br>
    <p>Supported Android devices: Compatible with all Samsung, LG, Motorola, and HTC phones running Android OS 6.0 or newer.</p><br>
    <p>Supported iOS devices: Compatible with all iPhones, iPads, and iPod Touches that have a Lightning Port. Requires iOS 10.13 or later.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>Which computers can I use to transfer photos and videos off of the device?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>By simply plugging in ThePhotoStick® Omni into your computer, you can easily transfer all of the photos and videos off of your device. It’s compatible with nearly all modern computers that use Windows or Mac Operating Systems.</p><br>
    <p>Windows: Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10.
    </p><br>
    <p>Mac: Mac OS X Version 10.6 and later.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>How do I start ThePhotoStick Omni?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>It’s as EASY as 1, 2, 3!</p><br>
    <p>1) Download and Launch the FREE “ThePhotoStick® Mobile” App 2) Plug the adapter into your phone or tablet and allow to search for files 3) Plug the USB stick into your computer and safely transfer your photos and videos</p><br>
    <p>(Optional) Plug into your computer to get the photos and videos off your device!</p>

  </div>
  <h3>What photo file size is used when we say the 128GB version can store 60,000 photos?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>We use an average photo file size of 2MB for our calculation. We picked this size for our calculation because it is the approximate size of an 8MP photo saved in a .JPEG format. Some file sizes are much larger, such as camera RAW files, movie files
      such as .MOV and .MPEG4, and photos taken with cameras that can take photos greater than 8MP, so the number of photos that can be stored on ThePhotoStick® Omni can vary.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>Can I use ThePhotostick Omni as an ongoing backup solution?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Yes, it’s a great backup solution! Many people plug ThePhotoStick® Omni in each night for a quick and easy backup to make sure they are continually protecting their memories.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>How does the 60 Day Money Back Guarantee work?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>All products are backed by our 60 Day Money Back Guarantee, starting on the day of shipping.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>Will I have to pay any additional customs, duties or VAT fees when I receive my order?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Depending on your country, it is possible that you will be charged one or more of these fees when you receive your order.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>How long does delivery take to countries outside of the U.S.?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>We ship orders out FAST, but we can’t control carrier transit times. Due to COVID-19, orders are taking up to 10-20 days to be delivered depending on the country.</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. I already move your code to a minimal reproduciable code snippet and added the `jquery` tag for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the property `active : 'none'` to the script to keep all accordions collapsed on page load.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active : 'none'
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Head -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Which devices are compatible with ThePhotostick Omni? </h3>
  <div>
    <p>Almost all major Android, iPhone, and iPad devices!</p><br>
    <p>Supported Android devices: Compatible with all Samsung, LG, Motorola, and HTC phones running Android OS 6.0 or newer.</p><br>
    <p>Supported iOS devices: Compatible with all iPhones, iPads, and iPod Touches that have a Lightning Port. Requires iOS 10.13 or later.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>Which computers can I use to transfer photos and videos off of the device?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>By simply plugging in ThePhotoStick® Omni into your computer, you can easily transfer all of the photos and videos off of your device. It’s compatible with nearly all modern computers that use Windows or Mac Operating Systems.</p><br>
    <p>Windows: Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10.
    </p><br>
    <p>Mac: Mac OS X Version 10.6 and later.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>How do I start ThePhotoStick Omni?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>It’s as EASY as 1, 2, 3!</p><br>
    <p>1) Download and Launch the FREE “ThePhotoStick® Mobile” App 2) Plug the adapter into your phone or tablet and allow to search for files 3) Plug the USB stick into your computer and safely transfer your photos and videos</p><br>
    <p>(Optional) Plug into your computer to get the photos and videos off your device!</p>

  </div>
  <h3>What photo file size is used when we say the 128GB version can store 60,000 photos?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>We use an average photo file size of 2MB for our calculation. We picked this size for our calculation because it is the approximate size of an 8MP photo saved in a .JPEG format. Some file sizes are much larger, such as camera RAW files, movie files
      such as .MOV and .MPEG4, and photos taken with cameras that can take photos greater than 8MP, so the number of photos that can be stored on ThePhotoStick® Omni can vary.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>Can I use ThePhotostick Omni as an ongoing backup solution?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Yes, it’s a great backup solution! Many people plug ThePhotoStick® Omni in each night for a quick and easy backup to make sure they are continually protecting their memories.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>How does the 60 Day Money Back Guarantee work?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>All products are backed by our 60 Day Money Back Guarantee, starting on the day of shipping.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>Will I have to pay any additional customs, duties or VAT fees when I receive my order?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Depending on your country, it is possible that you will be charged one or more of these fees when you receive your order.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>How long does delivery take to countries outside of the U.S.?</h3>
  <div>
    <p>We ship orders out FAST, but we can’t control carrier transit times. Due to COVID-19, orders are taking up to 10-20 days to be delivered depending on the country.</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: @cliffxpc Appreciate if you can mark the answer as accepted as it would help other SO users who are looking for similar answers